# Maven:resource duplicates files

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm using maven resources to copy my main/src/resources to my target folder. The problem is that once I package the project into a Jar, every file in resources appear two times:

1. target/MYPROJECT.jar!/main/resources
2. target/MYPROJECT.jar!/

[image]

My pom.xml remains as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>QuerySuggester</name>


<profiles>

</profiles>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
<build>

    <finalName>query-suggester</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <!-- <excludes> -->
            <!-- <exclude>wn31/*</exclude> -->
            <!-- </excludes> -->
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/scripts</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <!-- <resource> -->
        <!-- <directory>apps</directory> -->
        <!-- <excludes> -->
        <!-- <exclude>*</exclude> -->
        <!-- </excludes> -->
        <!-- </resource> -->

    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>





        <!-- The configuration of maven-assembly-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Specifies the configuration file of the assembly plugin -->
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <finalName>QuerySuggester</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <mainClass>xxxx</mainClass>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/wn31</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        xxx</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <!-- The configuration of the plugin -->
            <configuration>
                <!-- Configuration of the archiver -->
                <archive>
                    <!-- Manifest specific configuration -->
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <!-- Specifies the main class of the application -->
                        <mainClass>xxx</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

I tried using  by If avoid copying these file in the second place project won't work so I should delete it from the first place.

Any idea?

Edit 1: Showing the full pom.xml

Comment: First please show your full pom file and not only excerpts..furthermore have you tried a `mvn clean package`?

Comment: OK, full pom.xml added